# How can I attach a contact replying an email on Iphone with IOS7

Tags: ios, mail.app, contacts, iphone

I have not found a way to share a contact with someone that requested it by e-mail, I should be able to reply with an attached contact information, does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can send your Contact card via emai from the Contacts app.

[image]

The above was for Mac contacts, in your case for the iPhone there is a share contact with the same functions.

Share Contacts From Your iPhone Or iPad:

Open Contacts
Tap on a contact that you wish to share.
Scroll down and tap Share Contact.

You have three share options:

Airdrop (use only to share with other ios7)

Message

Mail

Choose the option you like, fill in the addressee details, and click Send.

Comment: Since the question is about replying with a vCard attachment, after following @Buscar웃's instructions, simply copy the **vcf** file and paste it into your reply. It's not as straightforward as it should be, but it's definitely possible.